# PHP how can i return call function (to avoid function scope)

Tags: php, call, require

I have two files:

**template.php:**

```
<div><?php echo $myVar; ?></div>
```

**controller**

```
class MyClass extends Base {
    public function view() {
        $myVar = 'hello world';
        $this->loadTemplate('main');
    }
}
abstract class Base {
    public function loadTemplate($template) {
        require_once("templates/$template.php");
    }
}
```

but this must not works because the require is in scope of loadTemplate function, how can i return the call to require function in the loadTemplate?
i want the require be included in the view() scope using single function like $this->loadTemplate(); and not using require_once($this->getTemplatePath())

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Generally what you're trying to do is accomplished by passing an array with your variables (`$this->loadTemplate(array('myVar' => 'hello world'))`) and then calling `extract($vars)` in the `loadTemplate` method.

Comment: ofc it's possible. also this solution consumes more ram and cpu time than simply relying on the class scope.

Comment: This would make it kind-of pointless to have `loadTemplate()` to be declared public. Besides, all I'm saying is that the asker cannot achieve what he's asking in his question, namely to require a file in one method, but with another method's local scope.

Answer (score 2):

simply use class members to access the variables in your viewscript

**Classes**

```
class MyClass extends Base
{
    public function view()
    {
        $this->myVar = 'hello world';
        $this->loadTemplate('main');
    }
}

abstract class Base
{
    public function loadTemplate($template)
    {
        require_once("templates/$template.php");
    }
}
```

**Template** main.php

```
Output: <?= $this->myVar ?>
```